# Difference between single and double quotes in Flutter/Dart

Tags: string, dart, flutter

I know that single and double quotes have at least some level of equivelence in Dart. For example,

```
var myString = "Hello world";      // double quotes
```

and

```
var myString = 'Hello world';      // single quotes
```

have no programmatic difference to my knowledge.

I keep seeing them used seemingly interchangeably in various examples and in some documentation. I'm wondering if there is a subtle difference that I am missing or if there is a recommended style to follow, especially in Flutter.

*This is a Q&A self answer after reading the Flutter and Dart style guides.*

Answer (score 94, accepted):

### Single and double quotes both work in Dart

```
final myString = 'hello';
```

is the same as

```
final myString = "hello";
```

### Delimiters need to be escaped

Use a `\` backslash to escape single quotes in a single quote string.

```
final myString = 'Bob\'s dog';            // Bob's dog
```

Same thing to escape double quotes in a double quote string.

```
final myString = "a \"quoted\" word";     // a "quoted" word
```

But no need to escape anything if the delimiter is different.

```
final myString = "Bob's dog";             // Bob's dog
final myString = 'a "quoted" word';       // a "quoted" word
```

Also no need to worry about the value passed into an interpolated string.

```
final value = '"quoted"';                 // "quoted"
final myString = "a $value word";         // a "quoted" word
```

### Prefer single quotes in Flutter

The [Flutter style guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#prefer-single-quotes-for-strings) recommends using single quotes for everything

```
final myString = 'hello';
```

except for nested strings

```
print('Hello ${name.split(" ")[0]}');
```

or strings containing single quotes (optional)

```
final myString = "Bob's dog";
final myString = 'Bob\'s dog';  // ok
```

The [Dart style guide](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#strings) appears to be silent on the issue.

Comment: The Dart style guide is indeed silent on the issue. A recommended style has been proposed and discussed many times, but there is no consensus that one style is universally better than another. Arguments for single quotes include that they are lighter on the eye and easier to type on a *US* keyboard. Arguments for double-quotes include that are easier to read because they stand out more, and you have more strings containing apostrophes than containing quotes.

Comment: You always have to quote a dollar sign either way as in "This costs \$100 dollars". I'd prefer no interpolation to happen when using single quotes so one could write 'This costs $100 dollars'

Comment: @TomTom101, You can use a raw string for that by prefixing the string with `r`. For example, `r'This costs $100 dollars'`. That works with single and double quotes.

Comment: I wish they would have just picked one of the other.