# How to use quotation marks in a text string in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I write quotation marks in a text inside do:

ex:  `child: Text ("One fine day I woke up from" Bad Mood "was Monday"),`

```
Container(      
    color: Colors.white,
    height: 50,
    width: 390,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 5.0 ),
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    child: Text ("2 لا تتطلب النية قول أي شيء بصوت عال، ولكن التركيز على عبارة "بسم الله".", textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
        fontSize: 25.0,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),),

  ),
```

Comment: FYI, this is covered in the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings).

Answer (score 22):

Dart strings literals have several ways to include quotes in a string.

There are three ways Dart string literals can vary:

- They can use single-quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).
- They can be single-line (one quote) or multi-line (three quotes).
- They can be raw (prefixed by `r`) or interpolated (not prefixed by `r`).

All eight combinations can be used:

- `"A string ${withInterpolation}"`
- `'A string ${withInterpolation}'`
- `"""A string ${withInterpolation} (can contain newlines)"""`
- `'''A string ${withInterpolation} (can contain newlines)'''`
- `r"A raw string, $ means nothing"`
- `r'A raw string, $ means nothing'`
- `r"""A raw string, $ means nothing (can contain newlines)"""`
- `r'''A raw string, $ means nothing (can contain newlines)'''`

You cannot include the string delimiter inside the string without escaping it. Escapes use `\` to ensure that the next quote character is used as string content, not a delimiter, but escapes do not work in raw strings—in a raw string, a `\` is just a `\` character, like a `$` is just a character and not an interpolation starter.

So, to include a `"` in a string, you can either use an escape, or use a delimiter other than `"`. This rules out only a `r" ... "` string which uses `"` as delimiter and cannot use escapes.

- `"a \"quoted\" text."`
- `'a "quoted" text.'`
- `"""a "quoted" text."""`.
- and all the other strings work too, without escapes, except `r" ... "`.

This gives you a lot of flexibility in writing strings. 
Using a raw "multi-line" string for its tripple-quote, even if it doesn't actually span multiple lines, allows you to have both quote characters and dollar/backslash in a string, like:

```
var complexString = r"""I don't know if "amazing" is what I'd call this $-price""";
```

You are only stuck if you need a raw string that contains both `"""` and `'''` sequences. In that case, Dart combines two adjacent string literals, even with different quotes:

```
var veryComplexString = 
   r"""Dart strings start with ", r", ',  r', """ 
   r'""", r""", ' 
   r"''', and r'''";
```

Finally, you can also use interpolations to include strings of other kinds:

```
var someStrings = "This string contains a ${'"'} quote character";
```

Comment: input - 26°28'24.82"N - pls help me with this, how do I create like:
String sample = input.

Answer (score 7):

```
child:  Text ('One fine day I woke up from" Bad Mood "was Monday'),
```

Reference : [Difference between single and double quotes in Flutter/Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014913/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
child: Text ("One fine day I woke up from\" Bad Mood \"was Monday"),
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 'dart_quote'

[dart_quote](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_quote)

There two types of quotes.

1. Quote as a Widget

   ```
   WidgetQuote(
    text: 'This is the sample text including Quotes.',
   ).quote()
   ```

[image]

2. Quote in String

   ```
   StringQuote(
   text: 'This is the sample text including Quotes.',
   ).quote()
   ```

[image]